# Erro "No such file or directory" ao utilizar o mkdir()

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário para fazer o upload de ficheiros, tenho então um `input` do tipo `file`:

```
<input type="file" class="fileinput" name="pdf"/>
```

Depois, caso tenha sido selecionado um ficheiro, quero criar uma pasta "*PDF's*". Se a pasta já existir não crio, mas se não existir crio dinamicamente e posteriormente faço o upload:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){                 
    $pasta  = '../pdfs/';   
    $ano    = date('Y');
    $mes    = date('m');

    if(!file_exists($pasta.$ano)){
    mkdir($pasta.$ano,0755);                    
}
```

Mas estou a ter um erro com este código:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in **mkdir($pasta.$ano,0755);**

Porque poderá este erro estar a acontecer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A questão é que o `mkdir` cria apenas um diretório, não uma sequência deles. Por exemplo, se você quer criar a path `arquivos/anual/2014/pdf/`, a pasta `arquivos/anual/2014/` deve já existir previamente.

No PHP 5.0.0 foi adicionado um terceiro argumento para mudar esse comportamento: `recursive`. O valor padrão dele é `false`. Então basta você mudar para isso:

```
mkdir($pasta.$ano, 0755, true);
```

Documentação: [**`mkdir`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php)

---

Se não é este o problema, pode ser a permissão do diretório parente. Talvez o usuário não possa criar a pasta lá. Verifique isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução e pela explicação! O problema é mesmo esse, experimentei criar a pasta primeiro, e deixei de ter o erro!